# Rename a column in SQL select for both SQL Server and Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

The following request is correctly written for SQL Server, but not for Oracle.

```
SELECT col1 AS 'col1_new_title',
       col2 AS 'col2_new_title',
       col3
FROM table
```

For Oracle, it needs to be an equal sign, with the new name in front.

Is there a way to write that request so that it's executable in both environments, without having to rewrite it each time?

Comment: It isn't strictly correct, single quotes shouldn't be used for that purpose. Try using double quotes instead. And these are column aliases you have not actually renamed the column which requires DDL.

Comment: "*For Oracle, it needs to be an equal sign, with the new name in front.*" - no, absolutely not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your statement is not working in Oracle is caused by the single quotes. In SQL identifiers need to be enclosed in double quotes if you want them case sensitive. Single quotes are for string constants.

So the following

```
SELECT col1 AS "col1_new_title",
       col2 AS "col2_new_title",
       col3
FROM table
```

should work on both systems (actually on *any* DBMS that follows the SQL standard rules for identifiers)

For SQL Server this requires the configuration option "ANSI_QUOTES" (or something similar I don't recall the exact name) to be set to `ON` - which I think is the default in any recent SQL Server version.

If you don't care about UPPER/lowercase identifiers simply don't use any quotes at all:

```
SELECT col1 AS col1_new_title,
       col2 AS col2_new_title,
       col3
FROM table
```

Comment: Quick, complete -- with extra explanations for me to learn. Can't expect better than that!  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using single quotes is accepted by sql server but the documentation on identifiers specifies double quotes or square brackets. So messsge is absolutely avoid single quotes for column aliases.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
       col1 col1_new_title
     , col2 col2_new_title
     , col3
FROM table
```

If you have no spaces and avoid reserved words then the barebones approach above would work in most SQL dialects.

Note oracle does not require `as`  much and in fact does not accept it in some circumstances such as table aliases.

If this bare approach doesn't work add double quotes to the column aliases.